# WooCommerce REST API: Only returns 10 categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm working with WooCommerce api v3, and when I call

```
$woocommerce->get('products/categories');
```

It returns only 10 results. I read the [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-product-categories) and there is no specification about how to list all categories from api, but I have more than 40 categories on wordpress.

Someone already had this problem before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can pass more parameters to the function as you can see in the [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-product-categories). This should work:

    <strike>`$woocommerce->get('products/categories', array( 'per_page' => -1 ) );`</strike>

Looks like -1 doesn't work to display all the categories, so a positive integer needs to be in place instead.

`$woocommerce->get('products/categories', array( 'per_page' => 99 ) );`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping. When I put this I crash my page =(

Comment: But it works when I change to 'per_page' => 100 Thanks!!

Comment: Is there any way to get all the categories in one go? I need to fetch all the categories and check whether or not the new category name passed exists, else create one.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you to get all categories at once

```
// find category at wp-Store with name and return it

async function check_wp_category(api, gisCategory) {
  let category = {
    wp_category_id: -1,
    isFound: false,
  };
  let flag = true;
let page_no = 1;
while (flag) {
    await api.get("products/categories?page=" + page_no)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.length == 0) {
                flag = false;
                return category;
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                if (gisCategory === response.data[i].name) {
                    console.log("category id in loop" + response.data[i].id);
                    category.wp_category_id = response.data[i].id;
                    console.log("wp_category_id value in loop" + category.wp_category_id);
                    category.isFound = true;
                    return category;
                }
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response.data);
        });
        page_no++;
    }
    return category;
}
```